# I want to create a column in a dataframe using a dict value from the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I'm having trouble figuring ou ta solution to my ploblem, so here it is:

I have this column "Cs/min - bruto" in my dataframe (df_refData):

```
0     {'10-20': 6, '0-10': 7.199999999999999, '20-30...
1               {'10-20': 1, '0-10': 1.1, '20-30': 0.9}
2     {'10-20': 0.30000000000000004, '0-10': 0.7, '2...
3               {'10-20': 1, '0-10': 1.1, '20-30': 0.9}
4     {'10-20': 0.30000000000000004, '0-10': 0.7, '2...
5     {'10-20': 6, '0-10': 7.199999999999999, '20-30...
6             {'10-20': 0.9, '0-10': 0.6, '20-30': 1.8}
7     {'10-20': 9.600000000000001, '0-10': 4.6, '20-...
8     {'10-20': 0.30000000000000004, '0-10': 0.7, '2...
9             {'10-20': 7.5, '0-10': 6.8, '20-30': 6.2}
10              {'10-20': 1, '0-10': 1.1, '20-30': 0.9}
11              {'10-20': 0.2, '0-10': 0, '20-30': 0.5}
12    {'10-20': 8.899999999999999, '0-10': 6.6, '20-...
13    {'10-20': 6, '0-10': 7.199999999999999, '20-30...
14              {'10-20': 0.2, '0-10': 0, '20-30': 0.5}
15            {'10-20': 0.9, '0-10': 0.6, '20-30': 1.8}
16              {'10-20': 0.2, '0-10': 0, '20-30': 0.5}
17            {'10-20': 7.5, '0-10': 6.8, '20-30': 6.2}
18    {'10-20': 9.600000000000001, '0-10': 4.6, '20-...
Name: Cs/min - bruto, dtype: object
```

I want to take every row of it and make the keys of the dict become a column in my original dataframe and the values of the dict, the values of the columns created by the keys. I tried using

```
df_refData.append(df_refData['Cs/min - bruto'].apply(lambda z:
```

but couldn't come up with anything beyond that. Also, the firt row of the dict list must append on the index=0 of the df, the second row on the index=1 and so on

Can someone give me a little hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pd.concat([df_refData , pd.DataFrame(df_refData['Cs/min - bruto'].tolist())], axis = 1)
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! Would you please explain why the .tolist() is important here? I've tried a similar method but not using tolist() and didn't get a good result

Comment: If you supply a list of dictionaries to pd.DataFrame it converts it to a dataframe with the dictioanry keys are the columns